# How do I disown a youtube-dl process and have it finish multiple downloads?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/) to download an entire playlist of videos.  I would like to do this overnight as the videos are quite long.  The first video continues to download after being disowned, but the program stops when it should download the second one, in fact, it doesn’t even finish the first one completely.

Is there a special way to disown and background this?  Currently I am using (mid-download) `Ctrl+Z`, `disown %1`, `bg`, and `logout`.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB on Ubuntu Server 19.10, which is why I am posting on here instead of Unix SE.

I will answer any questions in the comments.

Comment: Could you use screen or tmux?  Have you tried the nohup command?

Comment: You could use `setsid` for this, but (slightly steeper learning curve, much better reward) is to use **tmux**.  See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100590/5538 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107032/5538  The second one is closer to your use case as it is about running system updates in the background.

Comment: @Andyroo I haven’t considered Screen, but I’ll try it out.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information in your question to provide a *specific* answer, but [wrt `disown`, here's a resource](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/). I'm not terribly familiar w/ `youtube-dl`, but can you not just run the entire process in the background; i.e. `youtube-dl (args & opts) &`?